# What is the best way to solve square integer matrices of 8-bit?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, svd, gaussian-elimination, lu-decomposition

Assume that we want to solve this linear system:

$$A^TA x = b$$

Matrix $A$ is square and random integer of 8-bit, e.g numbers between 0 and 255. Vector $b$ is known as well and also integer of 8-bit. Same for vector $x$.

So now to my question:
What is the best way to solve a linear system if the matrix $A$ is square, integer and 8-bit? It must be safe to do this. I cannot handle a system that are non-invertible. Also $A$ contains noise as well.

- Backward substitution
- Cholesky decomposition
- LU decomposition
- QR decomposition
- SVD decomposition

Comment: When you say $Ax = b$, do you mean ordinary multiplications over integers or multiplication over integers modulo $256$?

Comment: @achillehui Ordinary multiplications. I can accept if $x$ is a float variable. But best way is $x$ where integer as well.

Comment: When you say it's a matrix of random integers that also contains noise, what does that mean exactly? The matrix entries are random, so what is the noise?

Comment: @FredFrey They have integer noise. That means if index (1,1) should have 56, then instead it has 59.

Comment: @DanielMårtensson I guess I don't understand what is meant by "should have 56." You say "Matrix A is square and random integer of 8-bit," which I interpret as "a square matrix with random entries." How do you distinguish the error component (E = 59 - 56 = 3) as noise?

Comment: @FredFrey Well, the matrix $A$ is a 256 long histogram that I turn into 16x16 matrix and sometimes that histogram is not perfect and contains some error measurements. That error is the noise.

Comment: @FredFrey I think my question holds to much information. Might become configusing. Sorry. solving $(A^TA)x=b$ and selecting a method for that is more intresting. $A^TA$ will result a symmetrical matrix.

Comment: You forgot an essential information, which is the matrix size.

Comment: When I read that you turn a histogram to a matrix, my hair stand on end ! What is the rationale ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust That's easy. Histogram has 256 elements. That can be represented by 16x16 matrix.

Comment: Thanks, I am not that dumb. What sense does it make to consider $A^TA$ with $A$ obtained by rearranging a histogram ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question seems to be non-sense. Let $U=\{0..255\}\subset \mathbb{N}$.

You want to solve in $x\in U^n$ (or, at least, obtain an approximation of $x$ -by modifying $A$-) the equation $Bx=b$ where $B=A^TA$, $A\in M_n(U),b\in U^n$ are known. Assume, in the sequel, that $n=10$.

Unfortunately, all the entries of $B$ are -in general- $>50000$ and the entries of $b$ are $<256$. Then the best approximation for $x$ is always $\tilde{x}=0$.

EDIT. Answer to the OP.

If you want a valid method for all $n$, you must assume that the $x_i$ are non-negative REALS, possibly bounded by $255$. We can use a least squre method.

I use the library NLPSolve (under Maple) "The NLPSolve command uses various methods implemented in a built-in library provided by the Numerical Algorithms Group (NAG)".

NLPSolve is an iteration method that gives (theoretically) the minimum of a non-linear function $f(x)$ under constraints of equality or inequality linking the variables $x_i$. Unfortunately, often we obtain only local minima...

Here we choose $f(x)=tr((Bx-b)^T(Bx-b))$ and the constraint $K$ is $\{x_i\leq 255\}$. The initial point is $L=\{0,\cdots,0\}$.

[image]

For $n=10$, we obtain solutions $\tilde{x}$ that are close to $(0,\cdots,0)$, for example

[image]

Note that the mean of $\dfrac{||B\tilde{x}-b||}{||b||}$ is $\approx 0.5$.

Comment: @Yves Daoust , Yves read lines 3-4  "Vector b is known as well and also integer of 8-bit. Same for vector x".

Comment: Right. So $x$ is known ;-)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What method do you recommend? LU, QR? SVD? Backward substitution?

Comment: @DanielMårtensson: `memset` with a zero argument will be faster.